# Fluid simulation Artifacts

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have created a waterfall scene of height 95feet (considering real life measurements) using flip fluids addon.

The material given to the fluid surface is complete transparent.

I have baked the simulation at 700 resolution and render engine used is cycles.

There is a blue colour appearing on the parts of water simulation in the rendered image.
I have changed fluid material and HDRI considering it might be the sky reflection but the issue remains the same.
[image: render image]

[image: render image]

[image: render image]

Comment: without seeing any of your settings - we can just guess. So i recommend providing your blend file (maybe an easier/smaller one with the same problem)

Comment: Just to be sure, have you tried rendering a frame in a world with a completely uniform colour? (If this is a lighting problem, it's a Blender problem.. if it's a Flip problem, BSE might not be the right place to ask)

Comment: Looks a bit like a shader issue ... like brighters areas represented by some Volumetrics ... or isnt there in your node tree colorramp node with forgotten blue color at the 0 or 1 position? :)  Chris +1